# LaunchBar/Quicksilver as a replacement of Spotlight?

Tags: spotlight, quicksilver, launchbar

I asked about the usefulness of spotlight [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/1247/how-useful-is-spotlight), as I don't like the drag that spotlight causes all the time.

What I found useful in Spotlight is those two.

- word lookup : spotlight opens 'Dictionary' App automatically when it can look the word up.
- search for PDF

And one of the answer that I got is from 'Dan Ray' saying "Personally, I disable it in favor of Quicksilver.".

I don't use Quicksilver, but LaunchBar, but it seems to me that LaunchBar doesn't look up the pdf. And, furthermore, it has an option to search in Spotlight.

and My questions are

- Can LaunchBar can do the two things? Look into Dictionary, and pdf search?
- Can QuickSilver can do the two things?

If one of the tools can do that, I guess I just disable Spotlight, and enjoy the speedup.

Comment: I use quicksilver and it can't search in pdf by default maybe can do it with some plugin or script.

Comment: Both QUickSilver and LaunchBar maintain an index of files (among other things) but as far as I understand they both rely on Spotlight for a lot of things. What drag is spotlight really causing you? Once the drive is fully indexed, there shouldn’t be any drag at all, unless you’re adding gigs of data every day that needs to be added to the index.

Answer (score 1):

QuickSliver has Spotlight plugin and Dictionary (which can fetch definition from dict.org plugin.

The spotlight plugin allows you to search for a string in either Finder, Window or a command window.

Answer (score 0):

Unrelated answer, but you may want to try [Alfred](http://www.alfredapp.com/). An actively developed alternative to Quicksilver.